# Generating the correct model.matrix input for Lasso Regression

Tags: r, lasso, matrix

I am trying to make a Lasso logistic regression to predict Y a bi-categorical variable, with 24 candidate quantitative predictors. I have 108 observations. This is how my data frame looks like for the first 3 rows:

```
> data.detect[1:2,]
  CONVENTIONAL_HUmin CONVENTIONAL_HUmean CONVENTIONAL_HUstd CONVENTIONAL_HUmax
1   37.9400539686119    63.4903779286635   11.7592095845857   85.2375439991287
2   23.8400539686119    80.5903779286635   15.0592095845857   125.837543999129
  CONVENTIONAL_HUQ1 CONVENTIONAL_HUQ2 CONVENTIONAL_HUQ3      HISTO_Skewness   HISTO_Kurtosis
1  54.9938390994964  65.4873070322704  72.8863025473031  -0.203420585259268 2.25208159159488
2  70.8938390994964  80.3873070322704  91.4863025473031  -0.117420585259268 2.91208159159488
  HISTO_ExcessKurtosis HISTO_Entropy_log10 HISTO_Entropy_log2 HISTO_Energy...Uniformity.
1   -0.751917020142877   0.701345471328916   2.32782599847774          0.219781577333287
2  -0.0887170201428774   0.793345471328916   2.63782599847774          0.184781577333287
          GLZLM_SZE        GLZLM_LZE          GLZLM_LGZE       GLZLM_HGZE          GLZLM_SZLGE
1 0.366581916604228 35.7249100350856 8.7285612359045e-05 11497.6407737833 3.22615226279017e-05
2 0.693581916604228 984.424910035086 8.5685612359045e-05 11697.6407737833 5.98615226279017e-05
       GLZLM_SZHGE         GLZLM_LZLGE      GLZLM_LZHGE       GLZLM_GLNU       GLZLM_ZLNU
1 4164.91570215061 0.00314512237564268 405585.990838764 2.66964898745512 2.47759091065361
2 8064.91570215061  0.0835651223756427 11581585.9908388 12.9796489874551 38.5375909106536
           GLZLM_ZP Y
1 0.219643444043173 1
2 0.112643444043173 0
```

I created a model matrix and response vector:

```
x=model.matrix(Y~.,data=data.detect)
y=data.detect$Y
```

But when running Lasso

```
fit.lasso <- glmnet(x,y,family = "binomial",alpha = 1)
plot(fit.lasso,xvar = "lambda",label=T)
```

[image]
As you see, I have much more than 24 predictors(299 in the x axe above)

When choosing the best lambda via cross validation

```
cv.lasso <- cv.glmnet(x,y,family="binomial",alpha=1,nfold=10)
plot(cv.lasso)
```

[image]

Same thing !

And when trying to extract the non zero coefficients from the best lambda model:

```
coef(cv.lasso)
2266 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
                                           1
(Intercept)                         1.098612
(Intercept)                         .       
CONVENTIONAL_HUmin-10.5599460313881 .       
CONVENTIONAL_HUmin-117.359946031388 .       
CONVENTIONAL_HUmin-13.0599460313881 .       
CONVENTIONAL_HUmin-154.359946031388 .       
CONVENTIONAL_HUmin-17.6599460313881 .       
CONVENTIONAL_HUmin-18.3599460313881 .        
CONVENTIONAL_HUmin-9.08171050452898 .
```

I looked to my model.matrix and and I think that's where the problem comes from For example, for the predictor CONVENTIONAL_HUmax, it's duplicated about hundred times !

```
  CONVENTIONAL_HUmax104.046018889744 CONVENTIONAL_HUmax104.837543999129
    CONVENTIONAL_HUmax105.682510733322 CONVENTIONAL_HUmax105.837543999129
    CONVENTIONAL_HUmax106.837543999129 CONVENTIONAL_HUmax107.173812970536
    CONVENTIONAL_HUmax107.837543999129 CONVENTIONAL_HUmax108.046018889744
    CONVENTIONAL_HUmax108.837543999129 CONVENTIONAL_HUmax109.837543999129
```

If you have any suggestion to fix this problem I will appreciate !

Comment: You need to fix your data. `CONVENTIONAL_HUmax` (and probably other columns as well) has been imported as a character variable although it should be numeric. The reason is usually that there are typos, comments in this column, Excel error messages, or that you have not specified the correct `na.string` to the function you are using for data import.

Comment: So, first step: check `str(data.detect)`.